# Can't see the text in SearchView widget suggestions

Tags: android, textcolor, searchview

I think my SearchView widget population is working.  However, all I see in the suggestions list are white text blocks.  When I select one of the white blocks I see an orange highlight and I see the text behind the orange highlight.  So it seems I'm showing white text and white background in my suggestions list.  Any ideas on how to change that?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can customize your searchView. You could try setting the backgroundcolor of your searchview to (Color.WHITE).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. I found that the root cause of the issue is related to theme I selected when creating the Android application project in Eclipse. I was using Android API 14, and originally I selected theme as None. I searched the web extensively and did not find an answer or even a similar question about this issue, which made me think that this is a very uncommon issue (most of people don't run into this issue). So I decide to create a new Android Project, with exactly the same components and set up, this time, only changed the theme from None to "Hollow Light with Dark Action Bar", suddenly, my search view suggestion drop down texts started to become visible. Now I went back to my original project, in AndroidManifest.xml, under Application tag, set android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar", the search view suggestion drop down texts start to become visible in my old project now.